# Ionic 4 Stencil PWA - Manipulating DOM elements

Tags: ionic4, stenciljs

I am trying out ionic 4 for the first time and I am trying to change the css style of an element on my page.

eg.

I have a div

```
<div id="foo"></div>
```

Now on `mouseover` I would like to move the div to a different position on my page.

How do I get the element #foo and change the position on mouseover in my component?

please note this is just an example of what I want to do and i have no interest in using CSS for this since it would not working for me.

I have done some reading on ionic 4 and the shadow dom but it still makes no sense to me.

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://www.joshmorony.com/building-a-pwa-with-stencil-an-introduction-to-stencil/) is what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot that actually made me understand that I was in fact not using angular but rather just stencil.

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not want to write any css and want to refer element in your controller, can use viewChild as shown below

In HTML

```
<div #foo></div>
```

In Controller

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
.
.
.

@ViewChild('foo') divRef: ElementRef;

constructor() {
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.divRef.nativeElement.style.background = "red";
}
```

Here is running code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dagbfg)

Comment: So I checked my node_modules folder and @angular/core doesn't seem to be present for ionic 4.

Comment: Please note that is a PWA, I installed the project using ```npx create-stencil ionic-pwa``` command.

Comment: @user3718908 that means you are not using angular